# Calculating $\sum_{k=1}^{N} k^rf_k$ less than $O(r^2)$ where f is the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, summation, computational-complexity, fibonacci-numbers

An integer $r$ is given, and the integer $N$ is up to $10^9$.
Let $f_k$ the Fibonacci series starting with $f_1=f_2=1$.

How can find an algorithm which calculates the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^{N} k^rf_k$ modular a given prime $p=10^9+7$ in the time complexity less than $O(k^2)$? It's hard to find the answer since it's not a polynomial form.
Any help is appreciated.

My original problem was :
Given $N, r$, calculate
$\sum_{i}^{N}\sum_{j}^{N} \gcd(F_i, F_j)\gcd(i,j)^k$, didn't know something similar was in Project Euler.

Comment: ...Not to be too impolite, but isn't part of the point of Project Euler problems figuring out how to do them on your own?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I didn't know this problem was at Project Euler, I was solving a different problem and it just popped up. The problem that I was originally solving was calculating something with gcd and Fibonacci.

Comment: Finding results modulo $10^9+7$ isn't really the sort of thing that just 'pops up', and it's very characteristic of the Project Euler problems in particular.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you watch the original problem? I don't even do Project Euler.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Could you give us the number of the problem in Project Euler that you think the question looks like?

Comment: I should apologize a bit; I did make the assumption that this was Project Euler, but it turns out that it's not the only place that suggests finding results modulo $10^9+7$. That said... a quick search for `modulo $1\,000\,000\,007$ site:projecteuler.net` turns up literally several dozen problems that ask for results in that form, so it is hopefully an understandable assumption.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki OK. I guess the reason why the number $10^9+7$ is used that much  on Project Euler (or on other informatic projects) is because $10^9+7$ is an "enough" large prime number with "enough" pretty form.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $h(r) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^r f_k$, then $r^2 = o(h(r))$ if $2 \leq n \leq 10^9$.

But OP says his question is actually to find an $\mathcal{O}(r^2)$ algorithm to compute $h(r)$. But clearly the vector $(1^r, 2^r, 3^r, ... , n^r)$  can be computed in $O(n \log r)$, and the vector $(F_1, F_2, F_3, ... , F_n)$ can be computed in $O(n)$, and hence $h(r)$ can be computed in $O(n \log r)$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the modular part. Can you check it again?

Comment: Yes I'm asking the algorithm with that time complexity, not the closed formula for the sum. Sorry for my bad wording